# Error undeclared variable when select using limit

Tags: php, mysql, select, limit

I have an error in my script select MySQL with limit. it said

> Gagal ambil data:Undeclared variable: $st

this is my script :

```html
include'../konekdb.php';
if(empty($_GET[start]))
{
$st="0";
}
else 
{
 $st=$_GET[start];
}
$query = 'SELECT * FROM pelanggan LIMIT $st,5';
$ambildata = mysql_query($query);
if(!$ambildata)
{
 die('Gagal ambil data:'.mysql_error());
}
include'tabel_pelanggan.php';
 
mysql_free_result($ambildata);
mysql_close($koneksi);
    
$query2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pelanggan");
$num = mysql_num_rows($query2);
$hal = ceil($num/5);
echo "Halaman :";
for($i=1;$i<=$hal;$i++){
$page=$i-1;
echo "[][<a href=$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]?start=$page>$i</a>][]";
}
```

can you help me? thanks before :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an error with you `$_GET`, you're missing the quotes around the key name.

Your `$_GET`,

```
$st=$_GET[start];
```

What it should be,

```
$st = $_GET['start'];
```

**Edit 1**

You shouldn't be using `MySQL` now as it is deprecated. Either start using `MySQLi` or `PDO`, you should also look in to prepared statements.

**Edit 2**

Also don't forget to change your `if statement` too.

From

```
if(empty($_GET[start]))
```

To,

```
if(empty($_GET['start']))
```

**Edit 3**

Your query needs to use double quotes or if you want to use single quotes you need to close the single quotes then add the variable on.

From,

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM pelanggan LIMIT $st,5';
```

To,

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM pelanggan LIMIT ' . $st . ',5';
```

Or,

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM pelanggan LIMIT {$st},5";
```

Comment: thanks but I've tried, it still "undeclared variable" :(

Comment: oh yeah it works !! I need double quotes. thank you.
but now, the page isn't work. what's wrong?